# Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: sql, oracle, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have recently downloaded the oracle database 12c enterprise edition. So I got Oracle SQL developer installed with the package. I started to create *new database connection* as given in the documentation.

**My problem is....**

[image]
When I  try to test or connect with the following field values:
Hostname: localhost
Port: 1521
SID: orcl (I have tried 'xe' as well but the error persists.)

I get the following error:

Status: Failure -Test failed: IO Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host, connect lapse 15080 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms.

**I have also tried to use different port numbers but the issue remains the same. Don't know what went wrong.**

Comment: check your server logs - something might be 'wrong' https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/297498_1.html

Answer (score 0):

If local server sqlplus connection is fine, and error occurs only for remote client such as sql developer, check your sqlnet.ora file to see if it has tcp.validnode_checking = yes. Valid Node Checking allows or denies access from specified IP addresses to Oracle services. Set tcp.validnode_checking = no and restart database listener should solve issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the connection setting to Connection Type=Basic and use SID (not Service Name).
[image: Connection Properties in SQL Developer]

If you use Connection Type=TNSNAMES or Service Name instead of SID - the connections will be dropped.